# Vimeo check if video is paused

Tags: jquery, vimeo, vimeo-player

Related question: [How to get video play paused status with Vimeo API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15973698/how-to-get-video-play-paused-status-with-vimeo-api)

I am trying to implement a toggle button, and I am not sure how to check to see if the video is in a paused state. All the examples I've seen deal with 2 separate play and pause buttons.

```
var iframe = $('#vimeo-frame')[0];
var player = $f(iframe);

$('#controls li.vimeo a').bind('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if( player.api('paused') ) {
        player.api('play');
       // yep video is paused, so now play it 
    } else {
        player.api('pause');
               // video was playing, so now pause it.
    }

});
```

I have tried `player.api('paused')` as it should return a boolean. `player.api('play')` and `player.api('pause')` work as expected. Can someone help me here.
Thanks.

EDIT with Brads suggestions:

```
var iframe = $('#vimeo-frame')[0];
var player = $f(iframe);

$('#controls li.vimeo a').bind('click', function() {
       var $this = $(this);
       console.log('clicked'); // triggers
       player.api('paused', function(paused) {
       console.log('inside paused'); // doesn't trigger
            if (paused) {
              player.api('play');
            }
            else {
              player.api('pause');
            }
       });

});
```

My research has led me to : [Where does this pause vimeo embed code go in my slider script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9429810/where-does-this-pause-vimeo-embed-code-go-in-my-slider-script) and http://jsfiddle.net/bdougherty/UTt2K/56/ but still doesn't quite work.

Answer (score 0):

Because the API uses `postMessage`, grabbing any data requires using a callback function. You should pass the callback as the second parameter to the `api` call. The value you're asking for will be passed as the first parameter to the callback.

```
player.addEvent('paused', function(paused) {
    if (paused) {
        player.api('play');
    }
    else {
        player.api('pause');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible you missed this line in the docs? (I know I sure did)

> If you’re embedding and controlling multiple players on a page or using our JS API library (Froogaloop), you should give each player a player_id that matches the id of the iframe element.
>
> http://player.vimeo.com/video/VIDEO_ID?api=1&player_id=vimeoplayer